# Define a preprocessor macro with preprocessor comands

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm using often a syntax like

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C"
#endif
void myCFunc();
```

so I tried to make a macro to have a syntax like

```
CFUNC(void myCFunc());
```

I'm not relly sure if it's something that can be done (can preprocessor execute its freshly generate code?)

The failed idea was something like

```
#define CFUNC(ARGUMENT) \
#ifdef __cplusplus \
extern "C" \
#endif \
ARGUMENT;
```

Is there a way make a macro that generates code for the preprocessor?

Thanks

Comment: Succinctly, the answer is no.  Not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two different macros depending on the context:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define CFUNC(ARGUMENT) extern "C" ARGUMENT;
#else
#define CFUNC(ARGUMENT) ARGUMENT;
#endif

CFUNC(FOO)
```

However, the common way to do this is the following. It includes the braces and can be used both in definitions and declarations.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERN_C extern "C" {
#define EXTERN_C_END }
#else
#define EXTERN_C
#define EXTERN_C_END
#endif

EXTERN_C
void foo(void) { ... }
EXTERN_C_END
```

Comment: Source text inside `#if` preprocessor groups can be indented for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can inverse `#define` and `#ifdef`:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define CFUNC(ARGUMENT) \
extern "C" \
ARGUMENT;
#else
#define CFUNC(ARGUMENT) ARGUMENT;
#endif
```

Comment: Source text inside `#if` preprocessor groups can be indented for clarity.